# Dygraphs: is it possible to plot in negative domain?

Tags: reverse, dygraphs

is it possible to have the x-axis on top and y-axis on right? I would like the 0,0 location at the top right of my plot. I have depth (as negatives) on the y-axis and positive value (0-1) on the x-axis. I am using `dateWindow: [1, -0.1],` to reverse the plot, and it looks ok, except the x-axis should be on top.

Comment: There's no simple way to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, that is what I was afraid of. I can kind of get by with the reverse x axis option for now.